# How to fastly concatenate videos with C# or Python

Tags: python, c#, video-editing

I need to shoot a lot of video files on ram and combine them in quick succession. The resolutions of the videos may be different.

I use "moviepy" in python for now but it's too slow.

I'm open to ideas.

**My python solution:**

```
concatenate_videoclips(clip_list, method="compose").write_videofile(
               c_dir + file_n + ".mp4",
               verbose=False, logger="bar",
               write_logfile=False,
               preset="veryfast",
               threads=multiprocessing.cpu_count(),
               codec="libx264")
```

Comment: Hello, why not ffmpeg, which is written in C? That means it should be faster most of the time.

Comment: I'm doing preprocessing in the background, it's pretty hard to do in C. Also, moviepy uses ffmpeg, but I don't think thread operations are working properly. Maybe in Python I can hold the video segments at a pointer address and combine them in C.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK for Windows](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/products/multimedia), which has .NET classes for video processing. (*Disclosure: I work for the SDK's vendor*).

One of the demos that come with the SDK is `ConcatSameSize`. This demo handles the simple case of concatenating 2 or more video files from disk, provided they have similar properties, such as identical frame dimensions for all files.
However, the toolkit allows easy modification of the demo's code to cover other cases as follows:

- Instead of reading the files from disk using the `ConvertCtrl.SourceFile` property and storing the output to disk using `ConvertCtrl.TargetFile`, the input and output videos can be in memory by using the `ConvertCtrl.SourceStream` and `ConvertCtrl.TargetStream` properties.
- If you need to work with video files that have different dimensions (frame resolutions), you can use the [LEAD Video Resize processing filter](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/multimedia/filters/lead-video-resize-filter-2-0.html) to perform on-the-fly resizing during concatenation.
- If you have videos with different frame rates, you can unify their rates using the [LEAD Video Frame Rate Controller filter](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/multimedia/filters/lead-video-frame-rate-controller-filter-2-0.html).

If you wish to try these classes and components, you can download the free evaluation using [this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads). During evaluation, there's free email and chat support in case you have any questions about using the functions or modifying the demo's code.